# Изображение заднего фона окна и размеры виджета

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qrc

[image: задний фон]

Добавил задний фон в программу в *Qt Designer*, но *VS* не воспринимает две библиотеки которые появились, но они нужны.

При использовании  `w.setFixedSize(435, 625)`, функция `self.resize()` перестаёт работать.

Этот код (**pistoll.py**) был сделан на *Qt Designer*, я просто добавил задний фон, но на 69-70 строке появились не понятные импорты, которые не считываются.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(435, 615)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/Fone/fff.jpg);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.backk = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.backk.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 320, 75, 26))
        self.backk.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: White;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.backk.setObjectName("backk")
        self.p2020 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.p2020.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 270, 81, 31))
        self.p2020.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.p2020.setObjectName("p2020")
        self.re = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.re.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 230, 81, 31))
        self.re.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: White;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.re.setObjectName("re")
        self.wedom = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.wedom.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 180, 101, 31))
        self.wedom.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: White;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.wedom.setObjectName("wedom")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 435, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.backk.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Назад"))
        self.p2020.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "p2020"))
        self.re.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RE-45 Auto"))
        self.wedom.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ведомый(Wigman)"))
import backfone_rc
import ss_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Теперь про `self.resize`, При использовании `w.setFixedSize()`, функция `self.resize` в методах перестаёт работать (может её надо указывать где-то в другом месте)?

[image: main.py]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
################################## Тут вызовы  ui файлов

from Apex import Ui_MainWindow # Основное окно начало
from testdelete import Ui_Form
from weaponsUIrepeat import Ui_other # окно Оружия
from wedomiy import Ui_MainWindow1 # окно пистолета wedomiy
from pistoll import Ui_MainWindow2 # окно пистолеты
from p2020 import Ui_MainWindow3 # окно пистолета p2020
from RE import Ui_MainWindow4 # окно пистолета RE 
from pp import Ui_MainWindow5 # окно пистолеты пулемёты 
from SMG import Ui_MainWindow6 # окно Пп сменщик 
from ISH import Ui_MainWindow7 # окно Пп ищейка
from R99 import Ui_MainWindow8 # окно Пп R99
from VOLT import Ui_MainWindow9 # окно Пп R99

class Apexhelper(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                          # + Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Apexhelper, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.setupUi(self)

# class Test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):                          # + Ui_MainWindow
#     def __init__(self, parent=None):
#         super(Test, self).__init__()
#         self.setupUi(self)

class Wedomi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):                            # + Ui_MainWindow1
    def __init__(self):
        super(Wedomi, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

class Weapon(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_other):                                  # + Ui_other
    def __init__(self):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__()     
        self.setupUi(self)

class pistoll (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pistoll, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
      #  self.setStyleSheet(' .QWidget {background-image: url(5555.jpg);}')

class P2020 (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow3):
    def __init__(self):
        super(P2020, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class RE(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow4):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RE, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class PP(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow5):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PP, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class SMG(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow6):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SMG, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class ISH(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow7):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ISH, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class R99(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow8):
    def __init__(self):
        super(R99, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class VOLT(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow9):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VOLT, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)             


# Начало основного класса 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
      
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)      #создали центральный виджет  
        # Начало класса apexHelper
        self.apexHelper = Apexhelper(self) # экземпляр класса ApexHelper
        self.apexHelper.weapon.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon) 
        # конец класса apexHelper

        # self.test = Test() ------------------------------------------------------

        # Начало класса Weapon
        self.weapon = Weapon() # экземпляр класса Weapon
        self.weapon.back.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)
        self.weapon.pistol.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        self.weapon.PistolP.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса Weapon

        # Начало класса pistoll
        self.pist = pistoll() #экземпляр класса pistoll
        self.pist.wedom.clicked.connect(self.gotowedomi) 
        self.pist.backk.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        self.pist.p2020.clicked.connect(self.gotop2020)
        self.pist.re.clicked.connect(self.gotoRE)
        # конец класса pistoll

        # начало класса R99
        self.r99 = R99()
        self.r99.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса R99

        # начало класса VOLT
        self.volt = VOLT()
        self.volt.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса VOLT


        # начало класса SMG
        self.smg = SMG()
        self.smg.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса SMG

        # начало класса ISH
        self.ish = ISH()
        self.ish.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса ISH

        # Начало класса p2020
        self.p2020 = P2020()
        self.p2020.back1.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        # конец класса p2020

        # Начало класса RE
        self.re = RE()
        self.re.back1.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        # конец класса RE

        # Начало класса Пистолеты-полемёты
        self.pp = PP() #экземпляр класса PP
        self.pp.backkk.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        self.pp.smen.clicked.connect(self.gotosmg)
        self.pp.ihek.clicked.connect(self.gotoish)
        self.pp.R99.clicked.connect(self.gotoR99)
        self.pp.volt.clicked.connect(self.gotovolt)
        # Конец класса Пистолеты-полемёты



        # Начало класса wedomi
        self.wedomi = Wedomi() # экземпляр класса Wedomi    
        self.wedomi.backtoweapon.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)                          
        # Конец класса wedomi

        #Начало виджетов
        self.stack = QStackedWidget()      # QStackedWidget видно сразу несколько виджетов                                                  # !!!               
        self.stack.addWidget(self.apexHelper)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.weapon)    # 1   self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.wedomi) # 2 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.pist) #3 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(3) - ломается
        self.stack.addWidget(self.p2020) #4 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(4)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.re) #5 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(5)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.pp) #6 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(6)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.smg) #7 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(7)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.ish)#8 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(8)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.r99)#9 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.volt)#10 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(10) 
        
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())  
           


        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) #вроде можно без этого ????????????????????????????????????
        hbox.addWidget(self.stack)
    
    def nameProgramm(self, w=0):
        if w == 0:
            self.setWindowTitle('Apex Helper')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('gg.jpg'))                         
        elif w == 1:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Weapon')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('rtg.jpg'))                             
        elif w == 2:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Wedomi')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('wedomiy.png'))       
        elif w == 3:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Pistol')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ty.jpg'))
        elif w == 4:   
            self.setWindowTitle('P2020')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('p2020.png'))
        elif w == 5:   
            self.setWindowTitle('RE-45 Auto')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('re.png'))
        elif w == 6:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Pistol-P')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('fgh.png')) 
        elif w == 7:   
            self.setWindowTitle('SMG')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('SMG.png'))
        elif w == 8:   
            self.setWindowTitle('ISH')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ish.png'))
        elif w == 9:   
            self.setWindowTitle('R99')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('R99.png'))    
        elif w == 10:   
            self.setWindowTitle('VOLT')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Volt.png'))                                           

    def gotomain(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

        self.resize(230, 625)
        
    def gotoWeapon(self):  
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

        #self.resize(435, 772)
        
    def gotowedomi(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotopistol(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(3)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotop2020(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(4)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotoRE(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(5)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoPP(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(6)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotosmg(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(7)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoish(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(8)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoR99(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotovolt(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(10)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()   
    w.setFixedSize(435, 625)                                      # --- ApexHelper(), +++ MainWindow
    w.show()            
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick https://github.com/Nanoxia123/wednesday18_00

Comment: Никита вы меня не поняли. Не надо публиковать картинки с кодом, не надо давать ссылки на ваш проект. Составьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример. который демонстрирует вашу проблему, т.е. уберите все что не влияет на вашу проблему. Пример должен быть воспроизводимым, т.е. он копируется из вопросы и запускается без ошибок и демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick Я добавил выше, всё что надо. Если вам потребуется весь код то выше есть ссылка на гит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вы пишите:
>
> Добавил задний фон в программу в qt designer,
> но `vs` не воспринимает две библиотеки которые появились, но они нужны

Не понятно что за `vs` и что за две библиотеки?
Вы создали файлы ресурсов **backfone.qrc** и **ss.qrc**.

Надо преобразовать файл **backfone.qrc** в файл **backfone_rc.py** и
**ss.qrc** в файл **ss_rc.py**

```
pyrcc5 backfone.qrc -o backfone_rc.py
pyrcc5 ss.qrc -o ss_rc.py
```

После этого раскомментируете строки:

```
#import backfone_rc
#import ss_rc
```

и строка

```
MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/Fone/fff.jpg);")
```

будет работать.

Вы также можете подробнее ознакомиться как создавать и
использовать файлы ресурсов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

---

---

> При использовании `w.setFixedSize(435, 625)`, функция `self.resize()` перестаёт работать

Дело в том что `self.resize()` это как бы рекомендованный размер,
`setFixedSize(435, 625)` жестко фиксирует размер виджета и
**`изменить его можно только новым`** `setFixedSize(222, 555)`.

Попробуйте внести изменения:

```
    ...
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())  
    # +++ 
        self.gotomain()                                   # +++ 

    ...

    def gotomain(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    #    self.resize(230, 625)
        self.setFixedSize(435, 625)                       # +++ 
        
    def gotoWeapon(self):  
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    #    #self.resize(435, 772)
        self.setFixedSize(435, 772)                        # +++    
    
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()   
#    w.setFixedSize(435, 625)                         # --- 
    w.show()            
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon 
#from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
################################## Тут вызовы  ui файлов

from Apex import Ui_MainWindow # Основное окно начало

from testdelete import Ui_Form
from weaponsUIrepeat import Ui_other # окно Оружия
from wedomiy import Ui_MainWindow1 # окно пистолета wedomiy
from pistoll import Ui_MainWindow2 # окно пистолеты
from p2020 import Ui_MainWindow3 # окно пистолета p2020
from RE import Ui_MainWindow4 # окно пистолета RE 
from pp import Ui_MainWindow5 # окно пистолеты пулемёты 
from SMG import Ui_MainWindow6 # окно Пп сменщик 
from ISH import Ui_MainWindow7 # окно Пп ищейка
from R99 import Ui_MainWindow8 # окно Пп R99
from VOLT import Ui_MainWindow9 # окно Пп R99

class Apexhelper(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):          # + Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Apexhelper, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.setupUi(self)

# class Test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):                    # + Ui_MainWindow
#     def __init__(self, parent=None):
#         super(Test, self).__init__()
#         self.setupUi(self)

class Wedomi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):             # + Ui_MainWindow1
    def __init__(self):
        super(Wedomi, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

class Weapon(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_other):                   # + Ui_other
    def __init__(self):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__()     
        self.setupUi(self)

class pistoll (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pistoll, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
      #  self.setStyleSheet(' .QWidget {background-image: url(5555.jpg);}')

class P2020 (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow3):
    def __init__(self):
        super(P2020, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class RE(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow4):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RE, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class PP(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow5):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PP, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class SMG(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow6):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SMG, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class ISH(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow7):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ISH, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class R99(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow8):
    def __init__(self):
        super(R99, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class VOLT(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow9):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VOLT, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)             


# Начало основного класса 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
      
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)      #создали центральный виджет  
# Начало класса apexHelper
        self.apexHelper = Apexhelper(self) # экземпляр класса ApexHelper
# ?        
# ?        self.apexHelper.weapon.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon) 
        # конец класса apexHelper

        # self.test = Test() ------------------------------------------------------

        # Начало класса Weapon
        self.weapon = Weapon() # экземпляр класса Weapon
        self.weapon.back.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)
        self.weapon.pistol.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        self.weapon.PistolP.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса Weapon

        # Начало класса pistoll
        self.pist = pistoll() #экземпляр класса pistoll
        self.pist.wedom.clicked.connect(self.gotowedomi) 
        self.pist.backk.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        self.pist.p2020.clicked.connect(self.gotop2020)
        self.pist.re.clicked.connect(self.gotoRE)
        # конец класса pistoll

        # начало класса R99
        self.r99 = R99()
        self.r99.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса R99

        # начало класса VOLT
        self.volt = VOLT()
        self.volt.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса VOLT


        # начало класса SMG
        self.smg = SMG()
        self.smg.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса SMG

        # начало класса ISH
        self.ish = ISH()
        self.ish.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса ISH

        # Начало класса p2020
        self.p2020 = P2020()
        self.p2020.back1.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        # конец класса p2020

        # Начало класса RE
        self.re = RE()
        self.re.back1.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        # конец класса RE

        # Начало класса Пистолеты-полемёты
        self.pp = PP() #экземпляр класса PP
        self.pp.backkk.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        self.pp.smen.clicked.connect(self.gotosmg)
        self.pp.ihek.clicked.connect(self.gotoish)
        self.pp.R99.clicked.connect(self.gotoR99)
        self.pp.volt.clicked.connect(self.gotovolt)
        # Конец класса Пистолеты-полемёты



        # Начало класса wedomi
        self.wedomi = Wedomi() # экземпляр класса Wedomi    
        self.wedomi.backtoweapon.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)                          
        # Конец класса wedomi

        #Начало виджетов
        self.stack = QStackedWidget()      # QStackedWidget видно сразу несколько виджетов                                                  # !!!               
        self.stack.addWidget(self.apexHelper)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.weapon)    # 1   self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.wedomi) # 2 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.pist) #3 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(3) - ломается
        self.stack.addWidget(self.p2020) #4 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(4)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.re) #5 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(5)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.pp) #6 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(6)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.smg) #7 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(7)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.ish)#8 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(8)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.r99)#9 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.volt)#10 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(10) 
        
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())  
# +++ 
        self.gotomain()                                   # +++ 


        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) #вроде можно без этого ?
        hbox.addWidget(self.stack)
    
    def nameProgramm(self, w=0):
        if w == 0:
            self.setWindowTitle('Apex Helper')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('gg.jpg'))                         
        elif w == 1:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Weapon')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('rtg.jpg'))                             
        elif w == 2:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Wedomi')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('wedomiy.png'))       
        elif w == 3:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Pistol')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ty.jpg'))
        elif w == 4:   
            self.setWindowTitle('P2020')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('p2020.png'))
        elif w == 5:   
            self.setWindowTitle('RE-45 Auto')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('re.png'))
        elif w == 6:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Pistol-P')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('fgh.png')) 
        elif w == 7:   
            self.setWindowTitle('SMG')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('SMG.png'))
        elif w == 8:   
            self.setWindowTitle('ISH')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ish.png'))
        elif w == 9:   
            self.setWindowTitle('R99')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('R99.png'))    
        elif w == 10:   
            self.setWindowTitle('VOLT')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Volt.png'))                                           

    def gotomain(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

#        self.resize(230, 625)
        self.setFixedSize(435, 625)
        
    def gotoWeapon(self):  
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

#        #self.resize(435, 772)
        self.setFixedSize(435, 772)
        
    def gotowedomi(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotopistol(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(3)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotop2020(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(4)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotoRE(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(5)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoPP(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(6)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotosmg(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(7)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoish(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(8)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoR99(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotovolt(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(10)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()   
#    w.setFixedSize(435, 625)                         # --- 
    w.show()            
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Apex.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(435, 615)

#                                                        vv       
#        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/Fone/fff.jpg);")
#        если изображение находится в текущем каталоге   vvvvvvv
#        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(fff.jpg);")

        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(kata2.gif);")
        
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
#        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #220000")
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #220000")
        
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.backk = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.backk.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 320, 75, 26))
        self.backk.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: White;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.backk.setObjectName("backk")
        self.p2020 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.p2020.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 270, 81, 31))
        self.p2020.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.p2020.setObjectName("p2020")
        self.re = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.re.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 230, 81, 31))
        self.re.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: White;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.re.setObjectName("re")
        self.wedom = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.wedom.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 180, 101, 31))
        self.wedom.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: White;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.wedom.setObjectName("wedom")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 435, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.backk.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Назад"))
        self.p2020.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "p2020"))
        self.re.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RE-45 Auto"))
        self.wedom.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ведомый(Wigman)"))

#import backfone_rc
#import ss_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: vs - это visual studio code

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер вы попробовали сделать то что я вам написал и запустить приложение ?

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь я понял, как это работает

Comment: всё прекрасно работает

Comment: я зашёл на один из вопросов по ссылке, которую вы кинули и вы сказали, что не всё можно сделать в qt designer. Но ведь ещё есть qt creator, который совершенно другой... Я хотел бы научится ещё писать код вручную, да не могу найти информацию... А по одной официальной инструкции не разобраться( А как учились вы?

Comment: А в приложение можно как-то гифки добавлять или такой поддержки нет?

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер все можно. Пробуйте, если что-то будет не получаться - задавайте новые вопросы. The End.